# Summing using sum case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have two tabels:

```
MonthlySalary]:

    MS_EmployeeID   MS_Semel    MS_Month    MS_Amount
    22222              9           1         4000
    22222              9           2         4000
    22222              9           3         4000
    22222              9           4         5000
    22222              9           5         5000
    22222              9           6         3000
    22222              9           7         2000
    22222              9           8         5000

MSVTransaction:

    MSV_EntitledIdNumber    MSV_PaymentAmount MSV_Month
    22222                        3000             1
    22222                        3000             2
    22222                        4000             3
    22222                        5000             4
    22222                        6000             6
    22222                        7000             7
    22222                        2000             8
    22222                        5000             9
```

And I'm trying to build a comparison table. The output should be like this:

```
MSV_EntitledIdNumber  MS_Semel Jan_MSV Jan_SML .... Aug_MSV  Aug_SML 
22222                       9     3000     4000         5000   5000
```

I started writing this:

```
select 
  distinct [MSV_EntitledIdNumber],
  [MS_Semel],
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (1) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as JanMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (1) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JanSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (2) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as FebMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (2) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as FebSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (3) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as MarMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (3) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as MarSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (4) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as AprMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (4) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as AprSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (5) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as MayMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (5) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as MaySML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (6) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as JunMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (6) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JunSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (7) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as JulMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (7) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JulSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (8) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as AugMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] in (8) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as AugSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] between 1 and 8 then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as TotalMSV,
  sum(case when [MS_Month] between 1 and 8 then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as TotalSML,
  sum(case when [MSV_Month] between 1 and 8 then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) - 
  sum(case when [MS_Month] between 1 and 8 then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as Delta
from [dbo].[MSVTransaction] as msv
inner join [dbo].[MonthlySalary] as SmlTbl on SmlTbl.MS_EmployeeID =
msv.MSV_EntitledIdNumber  
[MS_Semel] = '9' 
and msv.[MSV_EntitledIdNumber] in (select distinct [MS_EmployeeID] from 
[dbo].[MonthlySalary])
group by [MSV_EntitledIdNumber],[MS_Semel]
```

The results I'm getting are not correct. Any idea what is the problem with the code and how can I fix it in order to get the output I want? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `from` clause.  Try joining on the month number and using an outer join:

```
select . . .
from [dbo].[MSVTransaction] msv left join 
     [dbo].[MonthlySalary] SmlTbl
     on SmlTbl.MS_EmployeeID = msv.MSV_EntitledIdNumber and 
        smltbl.ms_month = msv.msv_month
        [MS_Semel] = '9'
group by msv.[MSV_EntitledIdNumber], [MS_Semel]
```